# show html checkbox as neither checked or non-checked

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox

I have an html checkbox that controls a list of checkboxes. I want this checkbox to display in a sorta "null" state where it is neither true nor false. Is this possible?

```
<HeaderTemplate>
   <div style="width:90px">
      Toggle:
      <input id="chkAll"  
      onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" 
      runat="server" type="checkbox" />
   </div>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. If a checkbox is displaying, it either has a check in it or it doesn't. It can't be displayed and not have either value.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to mark it up as a checkbox. It is technically a button that performs an action, so why not just mark it up as a button?

Comment: @Liggi - sure you can. open excel. Select the first row right click and select properties. check off word wrap. Then select the whole sheet by pressing the top left corner. right click and select properties. The checkbox is not in the checked or un-checked state.

Comment: @Alex - so you saying just make a button that says Check All and then switched to Uncheck all? Ya that could work. Not sure which to have it go to by default though...

Comment: @kralco626 Exactly. Decide which is more likely: people requiring lots of them pre-checked, or not. That'll decide what the default state should be

Comment: @Alex - The only reason I had opted for a checkbox is that it's a good visual reference for what clicking it does. They can associate it with the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a checkbox won't allow a custom third state. You need to find another way to handle it. A few come to my mind:

- Use a dropdown list with three values, or three radio buttons
- Use two checkboxes, one for assigned/null, second for checked/unchecked
- Use an image and javascript to fill a hidden numeric field (it could be a fake checkbox, but it will not match each browser's look and feel and could look weird)

Answer (score 2):

HTML doesn't natively support the notion of a three-state checkbox. You'd have to implement it with a custom control, using a combination of images and text.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, you can set a checkbox to indeterminate, which effectively represents a third state:

```
<input id = "test" type = "checkbox" />

<script>
    document.getElementById("test").indeterminate = true;
</script>
```

The OP by now is probably a pile of bones slowly turning to dust,
but the question still deserves a modern answer.

Comment: This is viable solution, however there are some quirks to it. This helped me out: https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Answer (score 0):

no it isn't. but you can add additional property like you have 'runat'.

```
<input id="chkAll"  
      onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" 
      runat="server" type="checkbox" null="true" />
```

or you can add "disabled" instead of "checked"

here is js plugin that can help you:
http://www.blueshoes.org/en/javascript/checkbox/

Comment: oh so your saying just add null for my own refference? I was more looking for a visual clue. Because I have a grid with some checked and some unchecked check boxes. And this one in the header can be used to toggle all the other ones. So I wanted a null state to signal they there are some checked and non-checked.

Comment: so use "disabled" - its standard html property, and for example on first click remove property. or if you want to be able to check "unchecked", to check\uncheck all - you can add additional field which will be displayed before all boxed checked\unchecked.

Comment: if you want just one checkbox use http://www.blueshoes.org/en/javascript/checkbox/